# How can I print my JSON data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I try to get a JSON file on my local host but on console I receive an array with my all objects from data.json but I receive the following error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/data/folder/data.json',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data); 
        var data =[];
        var covers = document.getElementById("covers");
        var blockTemplate = covers.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].cloneNode(true);
        covers.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].remove();
        data.info.forEach( function(obj) {
            block = blockTemplate.cloneNode(true);
            block.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute('href', obj.link);
            block.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute('src', obj.cover);
            covers.appendChild(block);
        });
    }
    });
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
var data =[];
```

From `success()`.

This is overriding the `ajax` response.

Comment: `info` is the name of my object which contain 6 arrays. then how is the way of grabbing that data?

Comment: @MarkusHayner Just remove `var data=[];`. You’re accessing `info` from an empty array which returns `undefined`. Then you’re trying to apply `forEach` on it. Because `undefined` has no properties, there’s also no `forEach` property on it, hence the error message.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = data.info;
    data.forEach( function(obj) {
      block = blockTemplate.cloneNode(true);
      block.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute('href', obj.link);
      block.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute('src', obj.cover);
      covers.appendChild(block);
    });
```

Comment: Now I can't receive the images. It receive the links but not the images `GET http://localhost:8888/data/folder/undefined 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: It might be some issue with your path with images you should look around that thing.

Answer (score 0):

Change `success : function(data) {` with `success : function(response) {` response in `success` and your `data array` is ambiguous. This will create problem. In javascript variables overrides when you'll define again.

Take a look here

[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript/500459#500459)

Answer (score -1):

In your case I think that "info" object of "data" is not defined or not received from server.

You can also loop your json object as shown below :

```
if(typeof(data.info) != "undefined")
    for(i in data.info)
         {
                var obj = data.info[i];
                block = blockTemplate.cloneNode(true);
                block.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute('href', obj.link);
                block.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute('src', obj.cover);
                covers.appendChild(block);
         }
}
```